# Stripe Subscription with 3d authentication failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, subscription

I am Implementing Stripe Subscription with 3d Authentication but Subscription got incomplete after successfull verification can anybody help me with this ?
Technology--- MERN--

Steps

1. Created PaymentMethod id from Frontend.
2. Then at backend api in body get paymentMethod-Id
3. Created a customer without payment method only basic info then created setupIntent and confirm it to get redirect url
4. Then waited for response in webhook setup_intend _succeed and get success response then updated customer and created subscription
   but after everything perfect subscription is incomplete status and giveing invoice hosted url on clicking on that it create subscription

## for Frontend passing Payment Method id to backend

```
 const paymentMethod = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: "card",
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        billing_details: {
          name: name,
          email: email,
          address: {
            line1: address,
            city,
            state,
            postal_code: zipcode,
            country,
          },
          // phone: "+1 555-555-5555",
        },
      });
```

## Backend

let customer = await stripe.customers.list({ email: email, limit: 1 });

```
  if (customer.data.length === 0) {
    customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email,
      name,
      address: {
        line1: billing.address,
        city: billing.city,
        state: billing.state,
        postal_code: billing.zipcode,
        country: billing.country,
      },
 
    });
  } else {
    customer = customer?.data[0];
  }

  const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
    payment_method: paymentMethod,
    customer: customer.id,
     confirm: true,
    usage: "on_session",
    metadata: {
      data: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    },
  });


 const confirmedSetupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.confirm(
    setupIntent.id,
    {
      return_url: `${CLIENT_BASE_URL}/check-payment-status/${pricePlanId}`,
    }
  );
```

**passing this return url on frontend**

## On webhook

event **setup_intent.succeeded**

```
 const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
      email: email,
      limit: 1,
    });
    const customer = customerList.data.length > 0 ? customerList.data[0] : null;

    if (customer) {
      await stripe.customers.update(customer.id, {
        name,
        invoice_settings: {
          default_payment_method: paymentMethodId,
        },
      });
    }

    // Check if customer has an active subscription
    const subscriptionList = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
      customer: account.customerId,
      status: "active",
      limit: 1,
    });
  
    let subscription = null;
subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
          customer: account.customerId,
          items: [{ price: pricePlanId }],
          metadata: {
            product_name: plan.name,
            userId: user._id,
            amount: plan.amount,
            credits: plan.credits,
            planId: pricePlanId,
            billingName: billing.name,
            billingEmail: billing.email,
          },
          payment_settings: {
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
          },
          expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
          off_session: true,
        });

c
```

an anybody tell me what is wrong in this code

Answer (score -1):

Your flow is not exactly what Stripe recommends in their docs. There shouldn't be any need to directly create a Payment Method or a Setup Intent for a Subscription integration. See [these docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements&element=payment) for the recommended integration guide.

Comment: but in India we have to do 3d authentication first for storing user card details with customer that's why i am doing this can you explain what is the better approach for that

Comment: The flow I linked automatically supports 3DS authentication. You can use these 3ds test cards to test it out: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards

Comment: should i use payment intent or setup Intent 
can you please connect me on linkedin for some queries

Comment: SetupIntent if just setting up the card for future payments. PaymentIntent if you also need to accept a payment right then and there.